# How can I import an external script src in angular.json?

Tags: angular

I have an external script that I want to add in my Angular 6 project

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY`

I know I can import this in the script tag in my index.html

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=KEY"></script>`

But I was wondering if there is a much cleaner way to do this? Such as importing from angular.json in the scripts section.

Comment: I think this was incorrectly marked as a duplicate.  The linked question does not address the possibility of "importing from angular.json in the scripts section".

Comment: I think so too.